# Displaying real-time data from firebase in .subscribe() to html using Angular 4

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I am using Firebase's Real-Time Database for getting my data in Angular 4 project, following are my files :

**trip-data.service.ts** :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
declare var firebase: any;
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';



@Injectable()
export class TripDataService {

finalItems;
public data: Array<any> =[];
public myData: any[] =[];
  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {

    db.object('/').snapshotChanges().map(action => {
            this.finalItems = { ...action.payload.val() };
            return this.finalItems;
          }).subscribe(item => {
            console.log(item);
            this.myData = item;
            console.log(this.myData);
          }
          );
    }
}
```

**list.component.ts :**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TripDataService } from '../trip-data.service';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.css'],
  providers: [TripDataService]
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
trips;
      constructor(service: TripDataService) {
            // this.trips = service();
            this.trips = service.myData;
            console.log(this.trips);
       }

      ngOnInit() {

      }

}
```

and I am getting proper **result object** from firebase in console, how should I show the same data in my html file as soon as I get the data from Firebase, and same should be updated on html page as soon as data is updated in Firebase Database?

Comment: Can anyone help me with this question? i am using "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc0"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `myData` variable is an `Array` and it is by default `[]`.
Array is **reference type**. So in your component when you write `this.trips = service.myData;` in your `this.trips` variable will be stored reference to that initial empty array. Than when your receive data in `this.myData` will be stored reference to new array.

The solution is to use next code, for example(if in subscription item is an Array):

```
this.myData.length = 0;   // clear array
this.myData.splice(0, 0, ...item);
```

Answer (score 0):

**trip-data.service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
declare var firebase: any;
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class TripDataService {

finalItems;
public data: Array<any> =[];
public myData: any[] =[];
  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {

   }

   returnData(){
      return this.db.object('/');
    }
}
```

**list.component.ts :**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TripDataService } from '../trip-data.service';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.css'],
  providers: [TripDataService]
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
trips : FirebaseObjectObservable<any[]>;

     constructor(service: TripDataService) {
            // this.trips = service();
            this.trips = service.returnData();
            console.log(this.trips);
       }

     ngOnInit() {

     }

}
```

**Template File:**

```
<h2>{{(trips | async)?.name}}</h2>
<p>{{(trips | async)?.department}}</p>
```

Comment: I am getting error : Property 'returnData' does not exist on type 'TripDataService'.

Comment: @GauravA. : this keyword was missed in the trip-data.service.ts file for the returning the function. I have edited the code. Now look into this. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: I tried that already before adding comment, but that didn't worked, it's showing error "Property 'db' does not exist on type 'TripDataService'" 
also in component file, for --> trips : FireObjectObservable<any[]>; its showing cannot find FireObjectObservable because it is removed in latest angularfire2

Comment: in "angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc0" this version, above mentioned code is working like a charm. Have not checked it with "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc0".

Comment: I am using "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc0", can you help me with that ? Sorry for not mentioning it earlier !